# error: cannot find symbol variable FileProvider Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy intentando adaptar mi aplicación Android para sistemas 7.0.0+ parece que uno de los cambios es usar FileProvider, estoy viendo tutoriales, parece fácil pero resulta que Android Studio 3 no me encuentra esta clase y estoy cargando desde gradle un android.support.v4 (donde creo que va incluida) tal que así:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

En el AndroidManifest.xml dentro de application añado el provider y me sale en rojo la clase "FileProvider"

```
<application
...
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>

        </provider>
```

...

Y luego cuando intento usarlo en una activity sigue sin reconocer la clase.

```
File file = new File(path + getResources().getString(R.string.downloadFile));
                                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23){
                                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.my.app", file)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                        }
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Santiago, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debes agregar el `import` para que pueda reconocer la clase [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), el import es:

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
```

esta clase no depende de una dependencia que tienes que agregar en tu archivo `build.gradle`, es del mismo Android SDK.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

ahora tengo otro problema me salta una excepción en la línea:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.my.app", file)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

donde **com.my.app** lo sustituyo por el paquete de mi app y me da esta excepción:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains /storage/emulated/0/prueba/app.apk

Si reviso desde un explorador de archivos esa ruta existe.

Mi archivo file_provider_paths es este y el manifest no da error, parece que lo encuentra

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <external-files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```